# win32 dll in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Can C# .net be used to create a win32 dll. If possible can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: As in a native, 32 bit dll that has no dependency on the .net framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it's not possible to write unmanaged code in C#. You're stuck with C/C++.

You can, however, write COM components in C# that can be called from any Windows application.

Answer (score 1):

No way, C# code will be converted to IL which will be run in the CLR. So you can not make a native win32 dll using C#.